# How to find the most optimised solution to iterate through windowed time stamps, multiple columns with lists and its values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a more optimised solution (pandas) to find out if the people who entered a particular room exits that particular room within 1 hour. The "Enter" and "Exit" fields are lists of names of people who entered/exited. How do i optimised my solution without using multiple for loops and itterows/ittertuples?

| Time Stamp | RoomID | Enter | Exit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:10:10 | 1 | Tom,Mary,Jane | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 00:10:12 | 2 | Nan | Harry, Jay |
| 2022-01-01 00:10:19 | 3 | Nan | Nathan |
| 2022-01-01 00:11:26 | 2 | Barry, Allen, Jerry | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 00:12:37 | 1 | Nan | Jack, Jane |

Resultant Dataframe should contain the name of the person who entered and exited within 1 hour.

| Time Stamp | Name | RoomID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:10:10 - 2022-01-01 00:12:37 | Jane | 1 |

There are too many for loops here that im confused how to even start iterating.

Thank you for all the help! Im new to pandas and would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: but Mary not is "Exit".  what is last dataframe? between need calculate time?

Comment: May you provide a reproducible code, of what you have tried so far? We may build up from there.

Comment: please write more info, where what take and calculate.

Comment: @Tornike this is a typo, I guess the user should be Jane ;)

Comment: @mozway yes, of course..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) afer [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) of the columns:

```
df['Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'])

df2 = (
 df.assign(Enter=df['Enter'].str.split(',\s*'),
           Exit=df['Exit'].str.split(',\s*'),
          )
   .explode('Enter').explode('Exit').replace('Nan', pd.NA)
)

out = pd.merge_asof(
  df2.dropna(subset='Enter')[['Time Stamp', 'RoomID', 'Enter']],
  df2.dropna(subset='Exit')[['Time Stamp', 'RoomID', 'Exit']]
     .rename(columns={'Time Stamp': 'Time Stamp Exit'}),
  left_on='Time Stamp', right_on='Time Stamp Exit',
  left_by=['RoomID', 'Enter'],
  right_by=['RoomID', 'Exit'],
  direction='forward', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1h')
             ).dropna(subset='Exit')

print(out)
```

Output:

```
           Time Stamp  RoomID Enter     Time Stamp Exit  Exit
2 2022-01-01 00:10:10       1  Jane 2022-01-01 00:12:37  Jane
```

Comment: just to add, the first assign statement is not needed if the values are already a list! thanks for the great solution @mozway

Comment: @Jerru I think you meant *"already **datetime**"* ;)

Comment: that and also the df.assign portion to split strings to explode! thank you so much :)